# How does the following quine work?

Tags: perl, quine

According to wikipedia :

> A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output

I saw this piece of perl code and am not able to figure out how it works.

> Save the following line in file `/tmp/p` and run the file as `perl /tmp/p`:

```
Illegal division by zero at /tmp/p line 1.
```

The output of perl /tmp/p is:

> `Illegal division by zero at /tmp/p line 1.`

How is the code working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, try to run it with warnings turned on:

```
$ perl -w p
Unquoted string "at" may clash with future reserved word at p line 1.
Unquoted string "tmp" may clash with future reserved word at p line 1.
Argument "tmp" isn't numeric in division (/) at p line 1.
Argument "at" isn't numeric in division (/) at p line 1.
```

The first two warnings are from the compile phase.

Let's look at the `Deparse` output:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse p
'division'->Illegal('zero'->by('at' / 'tmp' / 'line'->p(1)));
p syntax OK
```

In essence, the value of `at` divided by `tmp` divided by the return value of another method invocation`p` is passed as an argument to the method `by` invoked on the class `'zero'`. `at` and `tmp` are considered to be strings, and their numeric values are zero. Therefore, `at/tmp` results in the illegal division by zero error.

You will get the same error if you change the file's contents to

> `Stackoverflow hacker news one at /tmp/p line 1.`

If you are wondering how `Illegal division` becomes `'division'->Illegal`, see [indirect object syntax](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax), and [avoid using it](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html).

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to see you concentrating on improving the quality of your Perl code, rather than investigating obscure corners

But the answer is that the line is parsed as

```
'division'->Illegal('zero'->by('at' / 'tmp' / 'line'->p(1)));
```

and Perl uses zero for `'at'` and `'tmp'` because they are not valid numeric strings, so the first action is to evaluate `0 / 0` which throws the error